# How to get info about Gcloud logs similar to logs explorer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-logging

I am using  `@google-cloud/logging` package to get logs from gcloud, and it works nicely, you can get logs, event (and query them if needed). But how I can get the same info as Logs Explorer? I mean different type of fields which can be queried and etc:

[image]

On this picture you see **Log fields** like, `FUNCTION NAME` which may be a list of values. And it seems that `@google-cloud/logging` can't get this meta (or fields info)? So is it possible to obtain it using some other APIs?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking how Logs Viewer is determining the values that allows it to present you with the various log fields to filter|refine your log queries.

I suspect (don't know) that the viewer is building these lists from the properties as it parses the logs. This would suggest that, the lists are imperfect and that e.g. `FUNCTION_NAME`'s would only appear once a log including the Function's name were parsed.

There is a way to enumerate definitive lists of GCP resources. This is done using `list` or equivalent methods available using service-specific libraries (SDKs) e.g. [`@google-cloud/functions`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/functions).

The easiest way to understand what functionality is provided by a given Google service is to browse the service using Google's [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer). Here's [Cloud Logging API v2](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/) and here's [Cloud Functions API](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest).

You can prove to yourself that there's no method under Cloud Logging that allows enumeration of all a project's Cloud Functions. But there is a method in Cloud Functions [`projects.locations.functions.list`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/list). The latter returns a response body that includes a list of `functions` that are a type [`CloudFunction`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions#CloudFunction) that have a `name`.

Another way to understand how these APIs ("libraries") are used is to add `--log-http` to any `gcloud` command to see what API calls are being made by the command.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that I have to do something like this.